# Convert contract ETH to WETH via function call

Tags: solidity, erc-20, solidity-0.8.x

I'm attempting to write a simple solidity contract that can:

- receive ETH
- convert ETH to WETH
- display ETH balance
- display WETH balance

ETH operations appear to work as expected however whenever I try to call any of the WETH functions I receive an error and the transaction is reverted.

Is there something wrong with the way I am trying to instantiate or interact with the WETH token?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

interface IWETH is IERC20 {
    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw(uint) external;
}

contract Scrath {

    address private weth = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

    function sendEth() external payable {
        if(msg.value < 1000) {
            revert();
        }
    }

    function ethBalance() public view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance =  address(this).balance;
        return _balance;
    }

    function convertToWeth() external payable {
        uint256 eth = ethBalance();
        IWETH(weth).deposit{value: eth}();
    }

    function wethBalance() external view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance = IWETH(weth).balanceOf(address(this));
        return _balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your code injecting in a Ethereum testnet such as Ropsten, Rinkeby or Goerli.
Depending on the choice of testnet you'll have to change this line of code with the WETH smart contract address of testnet:

```
address private weth = [ADDRESS_WETH_SMART_CONTRACT];
```

Example:
If I'll decide to distributed my smart contract in Rinkeby testnet I'll change the `weth variable` with the address of WETH smart contract.

For Rinkeby the address WETH is: **0xc778417E063141139Fce010982780140Aa0cD5Ab**
(Check this [link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/token/0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab) for more information).

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that any interactions with other contracts will need to be simulated on a testnet? (as opposed to Javascript VM in remix)

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure you are the using the functions correctly?

"Note: Do NOT send WETH tokens back to the WETH contract. They will be stuck there, and that isn't the way to get them refunded back to you. To convert WETH back to ETH you need to use the WETH contract's withdraw function. The parameter, wad, is the number of wei to withdraw."